# What is the most appropriate way to wrap and vertically align checkboxes and radio buttons in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is my first major attempt at building a form with Bootstrap after 2 days of reading and researching about Bootstrap.  I was instructed to build a form that closely matches an old Access form.  I've included a portion of the form below.  It's a combination of inline and horizontal, and you're seeing the inline portion.

Am I syntactically correct?  Am I doing this right?

What is the Bootstrap-recommended way of wrapping checkboxes and radio buttons for an inline form?  Did I do it correctly in the examples below?

How do I vertically align checkboxes/radios inside a row?

Any love or advice or recommendations are always appreciated.

[image: Medium column view]

```css
.custom-margins {
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.strong-border {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.intro-row {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline">



    <div class="row intro-row">


      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <input id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" type="text" size="50" value="" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
        <label for="EmployeeNbr" class="control-label">Emp No:</label>
        <input id="EmployeeNbr" name="EmployeeNbr" type="text" size="6" class="form-control" value="" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-lg-3">
        <label for="SSN" class="control-label">SSN:</label>
        <input id="SSN" name="SSN" type="text" value="" class="form-control" size="11" readonly>
      </div>


    </div>


    <hr class="strong-border custom-margins">

    <div class="row custom-margins">


      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <label for="DateStamp" class="control-label">Verification Date:</label>
        <input id="DateStamp" name="DateStamp" class="form-control" type="text" size="10" value="" readonly>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-md-4">
        <label for="LastPayDate" class="control-label">Last Pay Date:</label>
        <input id="LastPayDate" name="LastPayDate" class="form-control" type="text" size="10" value="" readonly>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label for="NotaryReq" class="control-label">Notary Required?  </label>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="NotaryReq" name="NotaryReq" value="1">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <hr class="strong-border custom-margins">

    <div class="row custom-margins">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Status" class="control-label">Status:</label>
          <input id="Status" name="Status" class="form-control" type="text" size="2" value="" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="HireDate" class="control-label">Hire Date:</label>
          <input id="HireDate" name="HireDate" class="form-control" type="text" size="10" value="" readonly>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="TermDate" class="control-label">Term Date:</label>
          <input id="TermDate" name="TermDate" class="form-control" type="text" size="10" value="" readonly>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4 text-right">
        <label class="control-label">Currently Employed?  </label>
        <div class="radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">Yes:  <input type="radio" id="EmpY" name="currentEmployee" value="true"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label class="radio-inline">No:  <input type="radio" id="EmpN" name="currentEmployee" value="false"></label>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are, except for the radio buttons, if you want to make the label clickable then you should use the same way as the other inputs

```
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="EmpY" class="radio-inline">Yes:</label>
      <input type="radio" id="EmpY" name="currentEmployee" value="true">
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label for="EmpN" class="radio-inline">No:</label>
       <input type="radio" id="EmpN" name="currentEmployee" value="false">
    </div>
```